# Fading modals in Angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the most excellent [sexy Bootstrap modal for Angular](http://popdevelop.com/2014/07/sexy-splash-modal-using-bootstrap-css3-and-angularjs/), but have encountered a problem.

I am opening a new modal immediately after the sexy full-screen modal closes. However, the residue of the sexy modal - the background - remains until the new modal closes. Is there a way to hook an event up to the sexy modal that fires when the modal actually finishes closing? I don't want to set up a timer, that would be a bit dirty...

Any ideas greatly appreciated.